# iframe video overlaps padding container on ios

Tags: html, ios, css, video, iframe

When I visit my website on an ios phone, the iframe video overlaps the padding of its container and is so shifted (see the screenshot below). The problem doesn't appear on other phones or computers (even with the chrome mobile version). I use skeleton.

[shifted iframe video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYDaG.png)
Here is my html :

```
<html lang="en">
<body class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns video-container" title="Funix">
            <iframe class="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/209906189" width="1980" height="1114" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="six columns small-image nomarginleft" title="Sketches" style="background-image:url(/img/project/funix/funix_sketches.jpg)"> </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css :

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "OpenSans", "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.columns {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.small-image {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 70%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the width and height inline attribute from the iframe and add a style width height 100% instead?

Comment: @Richard yes I tried but it is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a reposive media query for mobile (not even needed maybe..) and remove:
**`object-fit: cover;`** this is the cause of the root . I would check this out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Some browsers like IE are not friendly with it.